# Python: Creating a number of lists depending on the count

Tags: python

Im trying to create a number of lists depending on the number in my header_count. The code below should generate 3 lists but i get a syntax error instead.

```
header_count = 4
for i in range(1, header_count):
    header_%s = [] % i
```

Comment: If you're going to generate 3 lists, it's very strange to set `header_count` to 4. Better to set `header_count = 3` and iterate `for i in xrange(header_count)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is my interpretation of what you want, I hope I guessed it right (you weren't very clear).

```
header_count = 4
headers = [[] for i in range(1, header_count)]
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
headers[1].append("this goes in the first header")
headers[2].append("this goes in the second header")
```

Comment: Im trying to create three lists indivually named. So I need header_1, header_2 and header_3 as lists

Comment: Why? That really is a bad practice. This way you use it as `header[0]`, `header[1]`, `header[2]`.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is to to create a list of lists:

```
header_count = 4
header = []
for i in range(header_count):
    header[i] = []
```

In the header variable references a list containing 4 lists. Each list can be accessed as follow:

```
header[0].append(1)
header[1].append("Hi")
header[2].append(3.14)
header[3].append(True)
```

Comment: `header[0].append(1)` is a index exception.

Comment: This doesn't work, maybe it should be:
`for i in range(1, header_count):
    header.append([])`

Answer (score 1):

If you need list names (as it seems from your comment to nightcracker answer), you can use a dictionary of lists:

```
header_count = 4
listDict = {}
for i in range(1, header_count):
    listDict["header_"+str(i)] = []
```

Then you can access the dictionary using header_1, header_2, header_3 as keys.

Comment: Please don't encourage bad practices.

Comment: That's what he seemed to have asked for! One can never know, maybe it was a curiosity even if it's a terrible practice.

Comment: A dictionary is the appropriate data structure if the names are dynamically generated and have some information content beyond a simple counter (see the answer to the following question [how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-to-a-while-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-to-a-while-loop)). If the variables names are redundant with a simple count or index, then a list is the appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global() to create these variables:

```
header_count = 4
for i in range(1, header_count):
    globals()[f"header_{i}"] = []
```

Note: you started your range with value 1, so you will create three empty lists:

```
header_1
header_2
header_3
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean by `header_%s`? `%` is the mod operator, of course you can't assign to an expression involving an operator. It's like writing

```
a+b = c
```

You can't assign to `a+b`, nor can you assign to `header_%s`.

Did you mean this?

```
header_lists = [[] for i in range(1,header_count)]
```